# What are generic Relations in django models

Tags: python, django

Someone has written this in `models.py`

```
documents = generic.GenericRelation(Document)
```

I want to know how its different from other types like `ForeignKey` and `OneToMany` fields.

I have not seen enough documentation on this

If found something [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#django.contrib.contenttypes.generic.GenericRelation)

But even at first place i don't undestood what does contentype does and why to use it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagine you have various objects in your db (images, videos, songs, etc), and to each of them you would like to add keywords. However you would like to have a single keywords table which will manage all of keywords for all objects with keywords. So the models will look something like:

```
class Image(models.Model):
    # ...

class Video(models.Model):
    # ...

class Keyword(models.Model):
    keyword = models.CharField(max_length=64)
```

So having the models, somehow you need to connect keywords to other objects. For that, you need to use many-to-many relationship:

```
class KeywordItem(models.Model):
    keyword = models.ForeignKey('Keyword')
    image = models.ForeignKey('Image')
```

This however does not work because this will only allow you to add keywords for images, however you also need to have keywords for videos, etc. In other words, the problem with this approach is that it restricts linking the keyword to a specific table, the images table. So the idea is not to do that but to link to any table, and then just specify to which table you are linking:

```
class KeywordItem(models.Model):
    keyword = models.ForeignKey('Keyword')
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    object = generic.GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')
```

The `content_type` specifies to which table you are linking and the `object_id` specifies what is the primary key of the row in the table to which you are linking.

Now the question is how to specify to what table are you linking? One solution is to hard code the choices (images is `1`, videos is `2`, etc) but that is error-prone since it will have to be maintained. As it turns out, Django solves this by using [content types framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/). What happens is that when you do your `syncdb`, Django assigns a unique number to each of the tables/models you have within your project. For me it's easier to think of it as table type id (as suppose to table id because tables themselves don't have ids). So this number later can be used to reference to specific table.

Then if the images content type (table type id) is `1`, and you want to link keyword with pk `7` to an image with pk `11`, you can do that by:

```
KeywordItem.objects.create(keyword_id=7,
                           content_type_id=1,
                           object_id=11)

# or using Django magic (this automatically figures out the content type):
KeywordItem.objects.create(keyword_id=7,
                           object=Image.objects.get(pk=11))
```

Hopefully this explains a bit about the concept of why you might need generic relations. Now for the `GenericRelation`. Using the above example, imagine you want to access all keywords for a particular image. You will have to do something like:

```
img = Image.object.get(...)
img_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(img)
img_keywords = KeywordItem.objects.filter(content_type_id=img_type,
                                          object_id=img.pk)
```

That however does not look clean, which is why `GenericRelation` is useful. It makes accessing reverse generic relations very easy. For that you have to add the following field to the `Image` model:

```
class Image(models.Model):
    # ...
    keywords = generic.GenericRelation('KeywordItem')
```

Now this will allow you to access the keywords by simply doing:

```
Image.object.get(...).keywords.all()
```

**Note of caution**

Generic foreign keys are tricky business, especially in Django due to somewhat tricky syntax. If you are beginner in Django, I would not recommend to do anything with them until are you comfortable working with foreign keys in Django and all of the "magic" Django provides (e.g. `related_name` parameter). Once you understand that, generic foreign keys will be much easier to understand and use.

Comment: Thanks for that buddy , that really explained everything to me. Hope Djnago people include this type of example in docs :). I am not clear about one thing. what do u mean by this line  `images table type id is 1`. what type are u talking about and where is that type stored

Comment: modified answer. hopefully this explains it better.

Comment: thanks buddy , i now get it. Actually i am editing the existing project and it has all that stuff.